# Is there a possibility to get room availability for a specific time through the google calendar API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to find out which rooms are available and which are not through the google calendar API?

[image: rooms in my calendar look like this]

I can create an event and see what room the event is in, but I did not find a way to get a list of rooms that are available in a specific time frame as in the picture. Is there a way to get exactly this information with an API call or something similar?

Comment: Maybe https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query would help? Have you researched or tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: I found a solution! I did not know that every Room has an own calendar that you can use the freebusy query on. Thank you!

Comment: @JulianRoma you can post the answer.